# find is not working with class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am newbie here

i am trying to get length of two forms by using following code but its not working it seems. i don't know whats going wrong with it or what mistake i made here..

```
  var a = "<div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'></div>";

  var b = "<div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'></div>";

  var add = $(a);
  var edit = $(b);

  alert(add.find('.controls').length); //its always returning 0

if(add.find('.controls').length != edit.find('.controls').length)
  alert('There is change in number of divs.');
else
   alert('no change.');
```

Demo http://jsbin.com/loyuv/3/edit
Thanks in advance

Comment: find is working with child elements not a current target element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following;

```
var a = "<div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'/></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'/></div>";

var b = "<div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'></div>";

var add = $("<div>", {
    html: a
});
var edit = $("<div>", {
    html: b
});
alert(add.find('.controls').length); //its always returning 0
if (add.find('.controls').length != edit.find('.controls').length)
    alert('There is change in number of divs.');
else
    alert('no change.');
```

Here is working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/Bntr3/**

**Update:**

```
var add = $("<div>", {
        html: a
    });
```

Converts enclose your current html string by `<div></div>`. So, your `find()` method will work on latest html string

```
<div>
<div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'/></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'/></div>
</div>
```

If you do not want to modify your html string, you can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like

```
 var a = "<div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'/></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'/></div>";

  var b = "<div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'></div>";

var add = $(a);
  var edit = $(b);
  alert(add.filter('.controls').length); //its always returning 0
if(add.find('.controls').length != edit.find('.controls').length)
  alert('There is change in number of divs.');
else
   alert('no change.');
```

Here is working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/Bntr3/2/**

Comment: thanks buddy worked like charm.. can you help me to understand var edit = $("<div>", {html: b});.

Comment: That code encloses your html string with `div`. See my updated answer for more detail

Comment: @user3164335 see my more detailed answer if you do not want to modify current html string

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/) :

> Get the **descendants** of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

`find` looks **inside** the elements of the jQuery collection. You need to wrap the whole to be able to find your top level elements :

```
var add = $('<div>'+a+'</div>');
```

Comment: can you give more details what exactly you are saying? or please suggest what should i have to change in variable

Comment: @user3164335 `find` documentation : "Get the **descendants** of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element."

Answer (score 0):

had done some changes to your code please check here

```
var a = "<div id='a'><div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'></div></div>";
  var b = "<div id='b'><div class='controls'><input type='text' name='abc'></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'></div><div class='controls'><input type='email' name='abc'></div></div>";

    var add = $(a);
    var edit = $(b);

if(add.find('.controls').length != edit.find('.controls').length)
    alert('There is change in number of divs.');
else
    alert('no change.');
```

see demo here http://jsbin.com/loyuv/5/edit?html,js,output